# Vector Application Question

Tags: vectors

I have been working on a few problems related to vector applications and I can never seem to get the angle right when it comes to my final result. For example, I have been working on this question:

> A small aircraft, on a heading of $225^\circ$ is cruising $150$ km/h. It is encountering a wind blowing from a bearing of $315^\circ$ at $35$ km/h. Determine the aircraft's velocity.

My answer was approximately $154$ km/h on a bearing of $103^\circ$
I got this by drawing a vector diagram to provide a visual. Then as the wind vector approaches the aircraft vector, it ended making a 90° angle. So I just used the Pythagorean theorem to solve for the resultant vector. Then I used the sine law to determine the angle and got a 77°. After this, is where I think I am getting mixed up. I extended the wind vector so it would end up in the second quadrant and subtracted the angle I got with 180° where I ultimately got 103°
The bearing is actually supposed to be $211.9° but I can’t seem to understand why that may be the case.

If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you also posted _how_ you arrived at your answer (i.e., the specific steps/calculations you performed). That'd help identify where exactly the issue lies.

Comment: @an4s Absolutely! I can edit it right now

Answer (score 1):

Bearing angles are measured *clockwise* with respect to the *positive $y-$axis*. The velocity of the airplane *before* encountering the wind is the vector $$v=\Big<150\cos\Big(\frac{5\pi}{4}\Big),150\sin\Big(\frac{5\pi}{4}\Big)\Big>$$ The velocity of the wind (which blows *from* a bearing of $315^{\circ})$ is the vector $$w=\Big<35\cos\Big(\frac{7\pi}{4}\Big),35\sin\Big(\frac{7\pi}{4}\Big)\Big>$$ The resultant velocity becomes $$v+w=\Big<-\frac{115 \sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{185 \sqrt{2}}{2}\Big>$$ which has magnitude $\|v+w\|\approx 154 \text{ km/hr}$ and makes an angle of $\arctan\Big(\frac{37}{23}\Big)+\pi$ radians measured counterclockwise from the positive $x-$ axis. This angle corresponds to a bearing of $\approx 211.9^{\circ}$.